# Is the partition of a manifold with embedded submanifolds a foliation?

Tags: differential-geometry, foliations

Let $\{S_a\}_{a \in A}$ be a partition of embedded connected submanifolds of a manifold of $M$ where each $S_a$ has the same dimension, say $k$.

Is it true that this a foliation of $M$?

I guess so:

By assumption: $M = \coprod_{a \in A} S_a$ and if $p \in M$, there is a unique $a \in A$ such that $p \in S_a$. Because $S_a$ is an embedded submanifold, there is a chart $(U, \phi)$ of $M$ such that $\phi(U \cap S_a) = \mathbb{R}^k \times \{0\}_{n-k}$.

My doubt comes from the following: my book claim that the following is not a foliation of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$\{(c,y): y > 0\}_{c \in \mathbb{R}} \cup \{(c,y): y < 0\}_{c \in \mathbb{R}}\cup \{(x,0) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

Clearly, this is a partition of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $1$-dimensional submanifolds. So it satisfies the above, so there is a contradicting lurking somewhere?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $p$-dimensional foliation of an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is a decomposition of $M$ into a union of disjoint connected submanifolds $\{L_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$, called the leaves of the foliation, with the following property: for every point $p \in M$, there is a coordinate chart $(U, (x^1, \dots, x^n))$ with $p \in U$ such that for each leaf $L_{\alpha}$, the components of $U \cap L_{\alpha}$ are given by the equations $x^{p+1} =$ constant, $\dots$ , $x^n =$ constant.

The non-example is not a foliation because there are no such charts for points on the $x$-axis. To see this, consider a point of the form $(c, 0)$. Suppose there is a chart $(U, (x^1, x^2))$ with $(c, 0) \in U$ such that for every leaf $L_{\alpha}$, the connected components of $U\cap L_{\alpha}$ are given by $x^2 =$ constant. Consider the leaf $L_{\alpha} = \{(c, y) \mid y > 0\}$. There is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that one component of $U\cap L_{\alpha}$ is $\{(c, y) \mid 0 < y < \varepsilon\}$, so there is a constant $k$ such that $\{(c, y) \mid 0 < y < \varepsilon\}$ is given by the equation $x^2 = k$. By continuity, $x^2(c, 0) = k$ which is a contradiction as $(c, 0) \not\in U\cap L_{\alpha}$.

Comment: Thanks! Some questions: Is the above general claim true? If not, why and why isn't the example a contradiction to the claim? And why are there no such charts? The x-axis $X$ is a submanifold and thus for every point $p= (x,0)$, there is a chart $(U, \phi)$ such that $\phi(X \cap U) = \mathbb{R} \times 0$? Thus we have component $x_2 = 0$ on $X \cap U$?

Comment: Please enlighten me where I go wrong!

Comment: The claim is false as the counterexample demonstrates. I have added some details, I can expand on them further if you need me too. The fact that there is a chart $\phi$ such that $\phi(X\cap U) = \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ is insufficient. In some sense, this chart only deals with one leaf of the foliation, whereas the required chart deals with all of the leaves.

Comment: Ah I see, the chart must work for all leaves... that was what I was missing

Comment: Just so I understand the definition of foliation: on $L_\alpha \cap U$, we have that the component functions are of the form $(x^1, \dots, x^p, c_\alpha^{p+1}, \dots, c_\alpha^{m})$ for every leaf $L_\alpha$, right? Thus, we don't say anything about the components $x^1, \dots, x^p$? They can be anything right?

Comment: In particular, if our chart is denoted with $\phi$, we don't have that $\phi(L_\alpha \cap U) = \mathbb{R}^p \times \{c_\alpha^{p+1}\}\times \dots \times \{c_\alpha^m\}$ right? I.e. the first $p$ coordinates can be "anything" so to say?

Comment: Almost. The intersection $U\cap L_{\alpha}$ may have more than one component. On each component, the coordinates $x^{p+1}, \dots, x^n$ are fixed and the coordinates $x^1, \dots, x^p$ vary.

Comment: Ah yes, it is a countable union of such sets. But are the first p coordinates forced to be $\mathbb{R}^p$ or can it be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$?

Comment: You can choose your charts carefully such that this is the case.